# update auto increment value

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to send an mysqli update via php.
A simple update is no problem.

But I have a auto increment row "ID"
Is there an way to update a row and update the auto increment ID value to the next possible value?

For example:

Before update:

```
ID | name
1  | Max
2  | Sabine
3  | Julia
```

After update:

```
ID | name
4  | Ronald
2  | Sabine
3  | Julia
```

Comment: Can't you just do `UPDATE table SET id = id + 3;`? Question is rather why do you want this?

Comment: you should **never ever** touch the unique identifier. It is not a number, it is not an order. It's just an unique identifier that **stuck to the row forever**. You'll run into innumerable issues doing things like that

Comment: okay, than I have find another solution. thanks ! :)

Comment: Updating auto increment value is possible, but you have to be aware with consequences of doing this, for example if you updated the id of the row  3|Julia  to 20 instead of 3, then when you insert a new record to the table it will start from 21 instead of 4.

Comment: @Hardood that's not actually a problem. There are much worse consequences like concurrency issues, collisions and conflicts. The rule of thiumb is: if you ever need to tackle with autoincremented id, you either doing it wrong or don't actually need this field at all